# Discord Bot don't load commands (.py - VS CODE)

Tags: python, discord.py

i have the full code of a discord bot and im using VS code to edit and run it (atm) but the bot dont load commands that are in a sub folder. when i run the but this message show up:

**RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
bot.load_extension(f'Commands.{filename[:-3]}')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback**

this is the end of code that should run my commands (folder name Commands, all commands end with .py):

```
for filename in os.listdir('./Commands'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'Commands.{filename[:-3]}')

token = '(my bot token)'
bot.run(token)
```

NEED HELP PLS

Bot works but the only commands i can run are in Non Category when i type =help

[MY FULL CODE](https://justpaste.it/dcyxw)

Answer (score 0):

Most discord.py functions are '[coroutines'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine), which is the case for `[load_extension]`[2](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension). You'd need to await `bot.load_extension`. This is also stated in the runtime warning you got. I'd suggest becoming familiar with asyncio and coroutines, as they're very common in the discord.py wrapper.

Hope this helps :)